# Stock picking creation fails with product - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I'm creating a `stock.picking` from `fleet.vehicle.log.services` like this:

```
@api.multi
def create_picking(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    vals = {
        'location_id': self.location_id.id,
        'location_dest_id': self.location_dest_id.id,
        'product_id': self.product_id.id,  # shouldn't be set on stock.picking, products are handled on it's positions (stock.move)
        'product_uom_qty': self.product_uom_qty,  # the same as for product_id
        'picking_type_id': self.picking_type_id.id
    }
    picking = self.env['stock.picking'].create(vals)
    return picking
```

The picking is created, this method is called with a button on view, like this:

```
<button name="create_picking" string="Crear Picking" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

My problem is, that `product_id` and `product_uom_qty` are not into `stock.picking` but they are called with a One2many field, on `stock.picking` model like this:

```
'move_lines': fields.one2many('stock.move', 'picking_id', string="Stock Moves", copy=True),
```

So, `product_id` and `product_uom_qty` are on `stock.move`, so when I click on my button, the picking is created, but it doesn't take the products, so, how can I add this relationship from my function?

Comment: Go to *Database Structure* and find out *stock.picking* object. Open that record and review where are required field to create recordset. Update your creation *vals* according.

Comment: Hi, no, the products aren't there, how can I relate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the lines of picking `stock.move` 
And then update the move_lines in `stock.picking`

```
@api.multi
def create_picking(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    #creating move_lines
    move_vals = {
        'product_id':your_product,
        'product_uom':your_uom,
        'product_uom_qty':product_uom_qty,
        'picking_type_id': self.picking_type_id.id,
        }
    move_ids = self.env['stock.move'].create(move_vals)
    vals = {
        'location_id': self.location_id.id,
        'location_dest_id': self.location_dest_id.id,
        'product_id': self.product_id.id,  # shouldn't be set on stock.picking, products are handled on it's positions (stock.move)
        'product_uom_qty': self.product_uom_qty,  # the same as for product_id
        'picking_type_id': self.picking_type_id.id
        #the move_lines here
        'move_lines':[(6,0,move_ids.ids)]
    }
    picking = self.env['stock.picking'].create(vals)
    return picking
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, but, could give me an example? I've asked that here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42614194/expected-singleton-stock-move-odoo-v9-community  but I'd like to leave the code cleaner as possible, I don't think the way I did on that question is the ebst way to go. Thank You.

Comment: Awesome! Thank so much!